# Importing Individual Contacts related/linked to Organizations causes Organizations to convert to Individuals

Tags: contacts, import

When importing a list of Individuals through the Contact Importer, I linked them to the Organization they are related to using "Knows" and the Contact ID for the organization, but after the Import went through all the Organizations were mysteriously converted to Individuals.

Is this a known bug?  Is there a way to convert the Individuals back to Organizations after this happens?  Or is there a way to avoid this issue altogether and link the Individuals to Organizations in bulk with them getting converted?

Update: Here are screenshots of the CSV as well as the field mapping just used on the WPdemo site where the issue was replicated:

- https://snipboard.io/xM98H1.jpg
- https://snipboard.io/UBcGDu.jpg

The following screen shows no errors reported with the import file:

- https://snipboard.io/RqhJIt.jpg

The results page shows that two records are updated, the Individual and the Organization it is linked to:

- https://snipboard.io/QeXPYE.jpg

After the input, Contact #95 is now an Individual instead of an Organization.

Edit #2: Here's a screenshot of the custom Relationship used in the field mapping for "Knows":

- https://snipboard.io/l9Kbn7.jpg

Comment: I would not expect the Org to have its Contact Type changed. Can you replicate on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org with a sample import. and screenshot your mapping

Comment: and apologies for seeming to roll out the same suggestion, but both of your tickets have given me a 'this doesn't sound right' reaction, and the best/quickest way to verify that, imo, is to throw the same task at a site that a/ we can both access, b/ is unlikely to have any odd settings that might be causing the issues. hope i can help you sort this through.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried the import on both the Drupal and WordPress demo sites.
In both situations, I needed to create a Dedupe rule for Contact ID and create a relationship type called "Knows".
When I imported to the WordPress site, the same error occurred - it converted the Organization into an Individual.
I was unable to import into Drupal because the "Knows" relationship doesn't populate in the Import field mapping drop down menus.
You can see on the WP demo that the Contact ID #70 is now linked to #13, but #13 has switched to being an Org.

Comment: could you add a screenshot to your Question of your sample import, and the sample mapping (or just the latter since it should show enough of the form) so i can replicate. thx

Comment: I just ran the test again, this time I did it on the WP site and the "Knows" relationship appeared in the dropdown.  The result was the same - linking the two together caused the Organization to flip to an Individual.  I'm going to also add a screenshot of the Custom Relationship too in case it gets removed from the demo site.

Comment: recommendations a/ do not use the same label at both ends of relationship - so try 'knows' and 'is known by' or something like that. b/ then set the contact type to be Individual for A, and Organisation for B.

Comment: second thought. test by importing same data with the Employer of relationship instead. i suspect it will work as expected, and fixing your Relationship may fix your specific problem